# Would adding a UNIQUE constraint on FK user_id for promotions stop a user claiming a promo twice?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to implement a use case where when a promotion is created for an e-commerce app, a user can only claim the promotion once. So if there is a special for $10 off a purchase, or something similar, a user can only claim that promo once now and forever.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
promotions

----------
id  | int
start | datetime
end  | datetime
claimed | boolean
user_id | int
product_id | int
```

Basically, if I add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the user_id foreign key that would stop a user from claiming a promotion once correct? The only thing about this would be what if I have a promotion the next day or a week from now? This wouldn't matter to the promotions table right because by the way it is set up now, a user can only have one promotion forever and won't be able to get a another one. Am I right with this assumption? If I am, how can I counter this?

Comment: Do you want it to be that way?

Comment: Hey @juergend thanks for responding. I'm a fuzzy headed right now, but I'm pretty sure I most definitely do not want it that way because like I said, I will want to do more promotions in the future. Do you have any suggestions. I could really use the help. Thanks.I was thinking about a CHECK constraint and adding an `expired` field on the table. Maybe I could do some logic to delete the promo after it was claimed.

Comment: If a promotion is for a specific product then you could add a unique key on `(user_id, product_id)`

Comment: That's a good point. That would solve the problem of a discount off a specific product. Thanks, I think I the wheels are turning again for me.

Comment: You could extract the date parts (day, month, year) from start_date and/or end_date, then create the unique index with that, the user_id and the claimed column.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store links to the users in the promotions table. Split the users from the promotions using a linking table:

Users <--M..M --> ClaimedPromotions <-- M..M --> Propmotions

And in the ClaimedPromotions table you should store with a UNIQUE constraint the links to a user & a promotion:

```
CREATE TABLE ClaimedPromotions
(
    user_id      integer not null references Users(id),
    promotion_id integer not null references Promotions(id),
    UNIQUE (user_id, promotion_id)
);
```

Due to the UNIQUE constraint on both columns, now it would be impossible single user to claim a promotion twice, but he can still claim multiple promotions.

In this way you will also not have duplication on the promotions data, like you would have in your original approach.